# What is the rail connection between Paris Charles de Gaulle Airport and Gare de Lyon like?

Tags: transit, trains, airports, paris, cdg

I'm hoping there is a regular shuttle service which is easy to find and fairly cheap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want direct, then there’s no direct rail option, but there’s a direct bus line, aptly named “Le Bus Direct”.

If you want rail, then there is no direct service. The easiest option is RER B to Gare du Nord then RER D to Gare de Lyon (same platform transfer in Gare du Nord).

Answer (score 14):

From the Airport you first catch the B line train to Chatelet – Les Halles, before then changing to the A line to Gare de Lyon. The whole journey takes no more than 45 minutes, and you will be able to catch the B line every 10-15 minutes. A single for the journey is about $10. There's huge signs around the airport that point you in the right direction, and you can buy tickets from many different machines that take both card and cash.

Alternatively there are options by bus, with at least one direct route, this takes over an hour though and costs around $17.

Comment: I would also like to point out that for this particular trip, the change at Chatelet - Les Halles is especially simple: you only need to cross the platform, there are no stairs involved (and thus it is impossible to get lost).

Comment: Changing my accepted answer. Sorry. At the terminal there was nothing, anywhere, to indicate any kind of train line. "B line train" was just not to be found.  But the bus was in your face, and took less than an hour.

Comment: @Stewart no worries! Later today I'll add some pictures from when I was there for any future readers :)